# How to compare value in two tables from the same database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to compare value in a table with another value in another table but only the else part is executing.

```
<?php 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=$row[user_id]";
  $result = $conn -> query ($sql);
  if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM jobpost WHERE jobpost_id=$_GET[id] ";

  $result1 = $conn -> query ($sql1);
  $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $row1_count = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
  $remaining_rows = min($row_count, $row1_count);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
  if($row["experience"] > $row1["experience"])
  {
    //some code to display something
    echo "1"; 
  }
   else
        {
         echo "2";

         }

    } } 
    ?>
```

Comment: from where you are getting `$row[user_id]` for first query?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, it is hard to read your source code. You can use a simple query like this:

```sql
SELECT IF(u.experience > j.experience,1,0) FROM 
(
  (SELECT experience FROM user WHERE user_id = 1) u
   JOIN
  (SELECT experience FROM jobpost WHERE jobpost_id = 8) j
)
```

Try this query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1742c0

Please check our datasource. Maybe the else case is correct.

Comment: The query works well but I'm having issue deriving php code from the query, it keeps on generating the wrong output, am sorry I'm a newbie